# ¿Cuándo se usa "plano" y cuándo "mapa"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones

Leo en el diccionario de la RAE:

**[Mapa](http://dle.rae.es/plano)**

> 1. m. Representación geográfica de la Tierra o parte de ella en una superficie plana.

**[Plano](http://dle.rae.es/plano)**

> 4. m. Representación esquemática, en dos dimensiones y a determinada escala, de un terreno, una población, una máquina, una construcción,
>      etc.

y me asalta una duda: ¿cuál de las dos palabras se debe utilizar cuando nos referimos a la representación de una ciudad?

A mi entender, usamos "mapa de Argentina" y "plano de mi casa", pero para la ciudad no sé cuál es el correcto.

Comment: En Chile siempre se usó "plano" para referirse al de las calles de una ciudad. Pero desde hace algún tiempo lo que se usa es "mapa", probablemente por la masificación de Google Maps y similares.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es cierto lo que indican las otras resuestas a esta pregunta con respecto al *sentido* de las palabras *plano* y *mapa* en el uso, considerando la función, la región lingüística y la formalidad.

Pero quiero agregar una distinción con respecto al *significado* de las palabras, que probablemente no nos sirva mucho en el habla cotidiana, pero que sí hace una diferencia en términos técnicos y además explica por qué hay dos palabras en vez de una sola.

Todo **mapa**, por ser una superficie plana, representa una imagen deformada de un sector del planeta, al ser éste un volumen esférico. Esa deformación se realiza mediante una técnica geométrica que se llama "proyección", que permite representar una superficie curva en otra plana.

Para un cartógrafo, un **plano** es un tipo de representación de un área lo suficientemente pequeña como para que no sea necesaria una proyección. Con escalas grandes, como las del esquema de las calles de una ciudad, la deformación dada por la curvatura del planeta es imperceptible.

Entonces se puede usar *plano* para referirse a la representación esquemática de cualquier "objeto" del tamaño de una ciudad o menor.

Comment: Fantástica explicación. Siguiendo con esta teoría, y siendo quisquillosos, ¿diríamos plano de una isla pequeña y mapa de una ciudad enorme?

Comment: Claro, pero hablando en términos técnicos.

Answer (score 4):

No creo que me llame mucho la atención cualquiera de las dos palabras en dicho contexto.  Eso dicho, si tuviese que pensarlo mucho (y quizás demasiado, creando una diferencia inexistente)...

Si hablásemos de algún documento que no se enfocara en ningún aspecto en particular o cuyo enfoque fuese geográfico/geológico y que fuese generalmente proporcional, creo que preferiría *mapa*.

Pero si tuviese algún enfoque en particular (las calles, el tránsito, etcétera) o si no fuese proporcional (es decir, esquemático), cuido que *plano* sería más conveniente.

Por ejemplo, si alguien me diese un mapa de la Argentina que tuviera sobrepuesto sobre él las líneas ferrocarriles, probablemente diría «Plano de FF.CC. argentinos» en vez de «Mapa de la Argentina con sus FF.CC.».  Igualmente preferiría «Mapa de Madrid» si hubiese un poco de todo, frente a «Plano callejero de Madrid» si el enfoque principal fuera la disposición de calles.

Answer (score 3):

A diferencia de lo que sugiere @guifa, en México el término `plano` se escucha mucho mas formal que `mapa`.

En general, podemos hablar de un `mapa turístico` de la ciudad a algo que no presta demasiada atención a escalas y detalles técnicos. El otro ejemplo sería referirnos a un `plano topográfico` de la ciudad, en donde los detalles técnicos son indispensables.

Answer (score 2):

Al menos desde un punto de vista ingenieril, un plano da información concreta y precisa sobre lo que representa. Un plano de una casa debe indicar las medidas, o si no las indica, al menos debe respetarlas. Si lo que tienes es un dibujo aproximado de cómo es la casa, entonces **no** es un plano. En este contexto, una muestra clara de por qué un mapa no es un plano son las carreteras: el trazado no es preciso, y desde luego la anchura que tienen en la imagen no se corresponde con la real. El mapa tiene una función diferente al plano.

Quizás no me he explicado del todo bien, pero creo que junto la respuesta de @Roflo se entederá lo que quiero decir.

Comment: Te expresaste fantásticamente. Muchas gracias por tu aportación, añade un buen pedazo de información (y sentido común) al uso.

Answer (score 1):

En mi opinión, un mapa hace referencia a información exclusivamente geográfica, mientras que un plano incluye información técnica.

De este modo, un mapa de la ciudad incluiría su distribución de calles, edificios, singularidades geográficas... ¿líneas de autobús o metro?

En el momento en el que sobre esa representación pasan a mostrarse distribuciones de tendidos eléctricos, canalizaciones de agua, etc... pasaría a ser un plano.

Comment: totalmente de acuerdo... por eso se llama googlemaps y no googleplanos o algo por el estilo