# What is behind the decline in usage of "carta" as a word for "map"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, historia, sustantivos, sinónimos

I was doing a Spanish **[Duolingo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duolingo)** lesson the other day when I got this:

> **[I have a map on my phone.](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/33344917)**

When I can, I try to avoid using the **[cognate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognate)**, plus I was a teeny bit fuzzy on whether or not "mapa" is masculine or feminine, so I opted for what I thought was the safer "carta."  Duolingo disagreed.  This was the correct answer:

> **Tengo un mapa en mi teléfono.**

So this got me to thinking *Isn't "carta" another word for "map" or have I been mistaken all these years?*  This then led me to do some research which I included in a post on Duolingo.  Since then, I got to thinking that this type of question was more likely to be answered and answered well via Spanish Stack Exchange, so I decided to post it here instead.  Below is what I had originally posted on Duolingo:

---

Does no one use "[**carta**](https://dle.rae.es/carta?m=form)" anymore for the word "[**map**](https://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=map)"?  Granted, **[WordReference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordReference.com)** no longer includes it in its list of definitions for "map," but if you do a search for "**[carta](https://www.wordreference.com/definicion/carta)**," it is definition #4:

[image]

and it is definition #6 for "[**carta**](https://dle.rae.es/carta?m=form)" in the [***Diccionario de la lengua española (DLE)***](https://dle.rae.es/carta?m=form):

[image]

If *carta* is no longer a word we can use for *map*, when did this happen and shouldn't the dictionaries above have some sort of note next to the meaning indicating that *carta*, when used to mean *map*, is now obsolete or *desusado (desus.)* as it is for definitions #7 and #8?  *(Not shown above, but if you **[link to the DLE entry for "carta,"](https://dle.rae.es/carta?m=form)** you can view them.)*

At the very least, it does appear to be on its way out, so I'll get with the program the next time Duolingo gives me "map," but the meaning of the word "carta" doesn't appear to be completely dead yet.  Nevertheless, I decided to do a little experiment with [**Google's Ngram Viewer**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Ngram_Viewer).  I went and found one of the most common **[collocations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation)** for "map" in English, translated it into Spanish, and then searched Google's Ngram database with them:

[image]

which definitely supports this decline in usage.  It does make me wonder why though.  Anyone happen to know?

Research has been somewhat cursory and mainly confined to Google searches of the web, but I did type in this question, without quotation marks, and even filtered out "Magna Carta," but nothing appeared to address this distancing of the word "carta" and the meaning of the word "map."  I know this forum has users with better research skills than I, so I'm going to leave it at this.

---

**¿Qué hay detrás de la disminución del uso de "carta" como palabra para "mapa"?**

Estaba haciendo una lección de Duolingo **[Español](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duolingo)** el otro día cuando vi esto:

> **[I have a map on my phone.](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/33344917)**

Cuando puedo, trato de evitar el uso del **[cognado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognado)**, además estaba un poco confusa sobre si la palabra "mapa" es masculina o femenina, así que opté por una opción más segura - "carta". Duolingo no estaba de acuerdo. Esta era la respuesta correcta:

> **Tengo un mapa en mi teléfono.**

Así que esto me hizo pensar *¿No es "carta" otra palabra para "mapa" o me he equivocado todos estos años?* Esto me llevó a hacer una investigación que incluí en un post en Duolingo. Desde entonces, me puse a pensar que este tipo de pregunta tenía más posibilidades de ser contestada y respondida bien a través de Spanish Stack Exchange, así que decidí publicarla aquí. A continuación está lo que originalmente había publicado en Duolingo:

[Véanse arriba en la parte inglesa.]

Si carta ya no es una palabra que podamos usar para "mapa," ¿cuándo ocurrió esto y no deberían los diccionarios de arriba tener algún tipo de nota junto al significado que indique que "carta," cuando se usa para significar "mapa," ya es obsoleta o está desusada (desus.) como lo es para las definiciones #7 y #8?  *(No se muestra arriba, pero si enlaza con **[la entrada del DLE para "carta",](https://dle.rae.es/carta?m=form)** puede verlas.)*

Por lo menos, parece estar saliendo, así que me pondré con el programa la próxima vez que Duolingo me dé "mapa", pero el significado de la palabra "carta" no parece estar completamente muerto todavía. Sin embargo, decidí hacer un pequeño experimento con el **[Ngram de Google](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Ngram_Viewer)**. Usando una de las **[colocaciones](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colocaci%C3%B3n)** más comunes de "mapa" en inglés, la traduje al español, y luego busqué en la base de datos de Ngram de Google con ellos:

[Véanse arriba en la parte inglesa.]

lo que definitivamente apoya esta disminución en el uso. Sin embargo, me hace preguntarme por qué. ¿Alguien lo sabe?

La investigación ha sido algo superficial y se ha limitado principalmente a las búsquedas en Google de la web, pero esta pregunta se buscó sin comillas, y aunque "Carta Magna" se fue filtrada, nada parecía abordar este distanciamiento de la palabra "carta" con el significado de la palabra "mapa". Sé que este foro tiene usuarios con mejores habilidades de investigación que yo, así que voy a dejarlo así.

Traducción realizada, en parte, con la versión gratuita del traductor [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator)

Comment: Not an answer, but a data point: in marine settings, the term "[carta náutica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carta_n%C3%A1utica)" is still used to refer to maps of the sea that are used for navigation.

Comment: As well as the term ["carta aeronática"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartas_de_navegaci%C3%B3n_aeron%C3%A1utica)

Comment: Related: [¿Cuándo se usa “plano” y cuándo “mapa”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12433/1674)

Answer (score 2):

"Mapa" is a representation of the terrain for general purpose, e.g. "Mapa de carreteras", "Mapa del tesoro", ...

"Carta" is a specific kind of map for navigation purposes, where it is required to fulfill some criteria to ensure the correct measures of distances and courses on the chart, avoiding distortions, eg. "aeronautical chart", "navigation chart", "low flying chart"...

For example, in the typical world map with Mercator projection, the distances are distorted and countries closer to the poles appears bigger than those closer to the equator.